# Display First & Last Name as a result in a php file format using the unique phone number from my database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have created a table 'details'-

```
FNAME-First name
LNAME-Last name
PHONE- Phone number
BIRTHDAY- Birthday
```

I have a html file with form,login.html-

```
<form action="check.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="phone">
<input type="submit" value="login"></form>
```

I have php file checking this with mysql database,check.php

```
<? $PHONE=$_POST['phone']
mysql_connect//My db details here
$query=SELECT FNAME,LNAME FROM 'details' WHERE PHONE='$PHONE' ?>
```

But the above php code shows error,I think i'm going wrong somewhere, any one can help?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really need to read a PHP tutorial or book.

Comment: where are "" or '' in $query? Check mysql_connect function in php.net there is red box read it! What about XSS?

Comment: @Robert, what does XSS have to do with this???

Comment: I know that "" or " in $query is neccessary ,In my actual code file of project I have mentioned it.

Comment: Well, post your actual code then!! And also post what error your get. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) carefully before asking your next question.

Comment: In your "actual" code you also put a `;` after `$PHONE=$_POST['phone']`? If not, put one.

Answer (score 2):

You giving an incorrect quotes to table name (change single quotes to backticks `),

```
$query = "SELECT FNAME,LNAME FROM `details` WHERE PHONE='$PHONE'";
```

**Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: The bigger problem is the query isn't encapsulated.

Comment: Judging from the question he has no clue what your "note" means. Better recommend a tutorial for absolute beginners to programming.

Comment: I'm new to this,,what are you saying about query I didn't understand.pls help

Comment: @AshiaTupe - What you don't understand ? About your issue or a note ?

Comment: It is giving an unknow T_STRING error :-(

Comment: Wait i will post my actual code.to solve my error.

Comment: You must be missing something..You need to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) your code, so that we can have a look.